# How to come up with proofs of these results? Or, are these results true in the first place?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, puzzle, reference-works

Let $x_n$ and $y_n$ be integer sequences determined by 
$$x_n + y_n \sqrt{2} = (1+\sqrt{2})^n \ \ \ \mbox{ for } \ n= 1, 2, 3, \ldots. $$

Then how to show that

(a) $x_{n+1} = y_{n+1} + y_n$, $\ \ \ \ \ $ $y_{n+1} = x_n + y_n$.

(b) $y_{n+1} = y_{n+1}^2 + y_n^2$.

(c) $y_{n+2} = 2y_{n+1} + y_n$. How to derive a similar formula for $x_{n+2}$?

(d) $x_{2n+1} = 2x_{n+1} x_n + (-1)^{n+1}$.

(e) How to derive general formulas for $x_n$ and $y_n$?

I was hoping to use induction or to be able to relate two terms of either sequences in some way but haven't had much success either way.

I wonder which area of mathematics this result belongs to!

And, I would be really grateful for a reference to some good book that deals with such matters.

Comment: (b) should be $y_{2n+1} = y_{n+1}^2 + y_n^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers defined by $x_{n} + y_{n} \, \sqrt{2} = (1+\sqrt{2})^{n}$ are called Pell and Pell-Lucas numbers.

As stated by the proposer question B should be $y_{2n+1} = y_{n+1}^{2} + y_{n}^{2}$ as will be shown.

---

1) From $x_{n} + y_{n} \sqrt{2} = (1+\sqrt{2})^{n}$ it is seen that
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} + y_{n+1} \sqrt{2} &= (1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1} = (1+\sqrt{2}) \cdot (x_{n} + y_{n} \sqrt{2}) \\
&= (x_{n} + 2 y_{n}) + (x_{n} + y_{n}) \sqrt{2}
\end{align}
which upon equating the coefficients the results become
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} &= x_{n} + 2 y_{n} \\
y_{n+1} &= x_{n} + y_{n}.
\end{align}
Notice that $x_{n}$ can also be seen in the form $x_{n+1} = y_{n+1} + y_{n}$.

2) difference equations: Let $n \to n+1$ in $y_{n+1} = x_{n} + y_{n}$ to obtain $y_{n+2} = y_{n+1} + x_{n+1}$. Now using the relation for $x_{n+1}$ this becomes $y_{n+2} = 2 y_{n+1} + y_{n}$. For the $x_{n}$ equation consider the following:
\begin{align}
x_{n+2} &= y_{n+2} + y_{n+1} = x_{n+1} + 2 y_{n+1} \\
&= x_{n+1} + 2 x_{n} + 2 y_{n} = x_{n+1} + 2 x_{n} + x_{n+1} - x_{n} \\
&= 2 x_{n+1} + x_{n}.  
\end{align}

3) explicit values: It can be determined that the same form remains when $\sqrt{2} \to - \sqrt{2}$ which leads to 
\begin{align}
x_{n} + y_{n} \sqrt{2} &= (1+\sqrt{2})^{n} = a^{n} \\
x_{n} - y_{n} \sqrt{2} &= (1-\sqrt{2})^{n} = b^{n}.
\end{align}
Adding and subtracting these relations it is evident that
\begin{align}
x_{n} &= \frac{a^{n} + b^{n}}{2} \\
y_{n} &= \frac{a^{n} - b^{n}}{2 \sqrt{2}}.
\end{align}

4) value of $y_{n+1}^{2} + y_{n}^{2}$:
\begin{align}
y_{n+1}^{2} + y_{n}^{2} &= \frac{1}{8} \left[ (a^{n+1} - b^{n+1})^{2} + (a^{n} - b^{n})^{2} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{8} \left[ 2(2+\sqrt{2}) \, a^{2n} + 2 (2 - \sqrt{2}) \, b^{2n} \right] \\
&= \frac{a^{2n+1} - b^{2n+1}}{2 \sqrt{2}} \\
&= y_{2n+1}. 
\end{align}

5) $x_{2n+1}$ equation.
\begin{align}
2 x_{n+1} x_{n} &= \frac{1}{2} \, (a^{n+1} + b^{n+1})(a^{n} + b^{n}) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} ( a^{2n+1} + b^{2n+1}) + \frac{1}{2} (ab)^{n} (a+b) \\
&= x_{2n+1} + (-1)^{n}
\end{align}
which can be seen in the form $x_{2n+1} = 2 x_{n+1} x_{n} - (-1)^{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

For example, and using an inductive argument:

$$x_{n+1}+y_{n+1}\sqrt2=(1+\sqrt2)^{n+1}=(1+\sqrt2)(1+\sqrt2)^n=(1+\sqrt2)(x_n+y_n\sqrt2)\implies$$

$$\implies x_{n+1}+y_{n+1}\sqrt2=(x_n+2y_n)+(x_n+y_n)\sqrt2$$

Thus, we have

$$\begin{cases}y_{n+1}=x_n+y_n\\{}\\x_{n+1}=x_n+2y_n\end{cases}\implies x_{n+1}=(y_{n+1}-y_n)+2y_n=y_{n+1}+y_n$$

Try now to take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

In fact  $$\eqalign{ x_n &= \dfrac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^n + (1 - \sqrt{2})^n}{2}\cr
&= \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n \choose 2j}\; 2^j\cr
y_n &= \dfrac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^n - (1 - \sqrt{2})^n}{2\sqrt{2}}\cr
&= \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor} {n \choose 2j+1} \; 2^j
}$$

The recursions can be derived from

$$\eqalign{x_{n+1} + y_{n+1} \sqrt{2} &= (1 + \sqrt{2}) (x_{n} + y_{n} \sqrt{2})\cr
&= (x_n + 2 y_n) + (x_n + y_n) \sqrt{2}}$$
so $x_{n+1} = x_n + 2 y_n$ and $y_{n+1} = x_n + y_n$. 
But note that you can replace $\sqrt{2}$ by $-\sqrt{2}$:
$$\eqalign{x_{n+1} - y_{n+1} \sqrt{2} &= (x_n + 2 y_n) - (x_n + y_n) \sqrt{2}\cr
&= (1 - \sqrt{2})(x_n - y_n \sqrt{2})}$$
so you also have $x_n - y_n \sqrt{2} = (1 - \sqrt{2})^n$.  Putting this 
and $x_n + y_n \sqrt{2} = (1+\sqrt{2})^n $ together, we can solve for $x_n$ and $y_n$.

For more (and there's **much** more), you might look at OEIS sequences [A001333](http://oeis.org/A001333) and [A000129](http://oeis.org/A000129).

Answer (score 0):

The unit group of the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is given by $\{ \pm(1+\sqrt{2})^n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, i.e., $1+\sqrt{2}$ is a fundamental unit of the real quadratic number field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Note that $(1+\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}-1)=1$, hence  $(1+\sqrt{2})^n(\sqrt{2}-1)^n=1$, so that all $(1+\sqrt{2})^n$ are invertible in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.

We have $(1+\sqrt{2})^n=x_n+y_n\sqrt{2}$, with $(a)$ and $(c)$. This can be proved by induction.
However, $(b)$ is not true, because already $y_{n+1}^2>y_{n+1}$, and $x_n,y_n\ge 1$.